# Headless installation: able to ping, unable to ssh (locally);

Tags: software-installation, noobs, headless

All,

I'm new to the RPI and have spent a couple of hours trying to do a headless install using NOOBS v1.4.0 on a RPI 2 (model B). Note that I need to perform a headless install because I only own a laptop and don't feel like buying a separate keyboard and monitor just to get familiar with this platform. Below is what I've done so far:

1. Formatted Micro SD Card (8GB) and copied NOOBS files over.
2. Connected Ethernet cable from RPI to router.
3. Connected power to RPI. PWR LED turns on. ACT (activity?) LED starts flashing erratically. After a moment I also see the orange and green LEDs in the Ethernet port of the RPI.
4. At this point my router's DHCP table shows the RPI's IP (192.168.1.113).
5. I ping this IP and get a successful response.
6. However, I try to SSH into it and get connection refused.

From what I've read on the internet ([link](http://hertaville.com/2012/09/27/raspbian-raspberry-pi/), [link](https://forgetfulprogrammer.wordpress.com/2013/06/03/raspberry-pi-headless-installation/)), it seems like I should be able to SSH into the device at this point.

Using Nmap I was able to confirm I was indeed pinging the RPI. Furthermore, it says all 1000 scanned ports (first thousand) were closed... Wouldn't port 22 have been listed as open if the ssh server was running the the RPI?

```
nmap -p 1-1000 -T4 -A -v 192.168.1.113

Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-04-19 19:40 Eastern Daylight Time
NSE: Loaded 118 scripts for scanning.
NSE: Script Pre-scanning.
Initiating ARP Ping Scan at 19:40
Scanning 192.168.1.113 [1 port]
Completed ARP Ping Scan at 19:40, 0.50s elapsed (1 total hosts
Initiating Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 19:40
Completed Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 19:40, 0.02s elapsed
Initiating SYN Stealth Scan at 19:40
Scanning 192.168.1.113 [1000 ports]
Completed SYN Stealth Scan at 19:40, 0.89s elapsed (1000 total ports)
Initiating Service scan at 19:40
Initiating OS detection (try #1) against 192.168.1.113
Retrying OS detection (try #2) against 192.168.1.113
NSE: Script scanning 192.168.1.113.
Initiating NSE at 19:40
Completed NSE at 19:40, 0.00s elapsed
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.113
Host is up (0.0019s latency).
All 1000 scanned ports on 192.168.1.113 are closed
MAC Address: B8:27:EB:8E:FA:EC (Raspberry Pi Foundation)
Too many fingerprints match this host to give specific OS details
Network Distance: 1 hop

TRACEROUTE
HOP RTT     ADDRESS
1   1.89 ms 192.168.1.113
```

So, what other troubleshooting steps may I take to narrow down my problem?

Any hints/ideas are very much appreciated!

Comment: Note that BOTH of the links you included ("From what I've read on the internet (link, link)...") **explicitly refer to Raspbian, not NOOBS**.   Hence it is not surprising they did not work.   It's maybe sort of an understandable mistake since NOOBS includes Raspbian, but they are still not the same thing.  When in doubt, ask a simple question first, it may save you a more convoluted question later.

Comment: To explain a bit:  You can install Raspbian via NOOBS, which is what I think you are trying to do, or you can just install Raspbian alone, which is what those blog links tackle.   BTW, if you at least have an HDMI TV it is worth $10 to buy a cheap keyboard for when you occasionally need to debug something without depending on a network connection.

Answer (score 0):

You could always get a usb UART converter (5 bucks free shipping Amazon) and connect to UART 0 on the pi. This will be cheaper than a laptop/keyboard and will let you sort your ssh issues